# How to calculate total?

Tags: javascript

I faced a problem for my code and I could not solve it. I have 2 functions, the first one calculates the total and second one discounts the total (if the user write the discount code, it will show the discounted total). But I don't know how to get and call the right value from total to keep it in the second function to calculate the discount because it always shows 0 in the amount. The TOTAL is for  the first function and JavaScript code is for the second function.

```js
total = parseInt(TicketsPrice[i].value) * parseInt(NOfTictet);
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

function discount(coupon) {
  var yCoupon = "winner1";
  var price = Number(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
  var amount;
  var input = document.getElementById('discount').value;

  if (input == coupon) {
    amount = price || 0 * 0.25;
    document.getElementById("Offerprice").innerHTML = amount;

  } else {
    alert("Invalid");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="coupon" id="discount">
<button onclick="discount()">discount</button>
<p id="total"></p>
<p><span id="Offerprice"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
function discount() {
    var coupon = "winner1";
    var price = Number(document.getElementById('total').value); 
    var input = document.getElementById('discount').value;
 
    if (input == coupon) {
       var amount = price * (1 - .25)  // 25% off coupon
       document.getElementById("Offerprice").innerHTML = amount;
    } else {
       document.getElementById("Offerprice").innerHTML = 'Invalid coupon'
    }
}
```

```html
<div>Total: <input id="total"></div>
<div>Coupon: <input id="discount"></div>
<button onclick="discount()">  discount</button>

<p><span id ="Offerprice"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code. Here is a working version. I hardcoded the total only for testing because I don't know the HTML for your tickets:

```js
var total = 500; //This is only for testing.
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

function discount() {
  var coupon = "winner1";
  var price = Number(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
  var input = document.getElementById('discount').value;

  if (input == coupon) {
    var amount = price * 0.75; //discount of 25%
    document.getElementById("Offerprice").innerHTML = amount;

  } else {
    alert("Invalid");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="coupon" id="discount">
<button onclick="discount()">discount</button>
<p id="total"></p>
<p><span id="Offerprice"></span></p>
```